# Brute force closest pair algorithms - for loops

Tags: python

New to Python. Trying to analyze the algorithm for Closest pair of points. Found an [example](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Closest-pair_problem#Python)

Which has these lines:

```
return min( ((abs(point[i] - point[j]), (point[i], point[j]))
                 for i in range(numPoints-1)
                 for j in range(i+1,numPoints)),
                key=itemgetter(0))
```

It is not clear to me how the for loops are being evaluated.

How are  the for loops related to the points, key and itemgetter?

When I put this code in [Ideone](http://ideone.com/1u27f9)

I get a runtime error in the times() function:

```
def times():
    ''' Time the different functions
    '''
    import timeit

    functions = [bruteForceClosestPair, closestPair]
    for f in functions:
        print 'Time for', f.__name__, timeit.Timer(
            '%s(pointList)' % f.__name__,
            'from closestpair import %s, pointList' % f.__name__).timeit(number=1)
```

Thank you.

Comment: `(expr for i in iter)` returns a tuple with `expr` evaluated for each `i` in the `iter` iterable. In this case, there are two for statements, so python calculates that like a nested loop. that means, for each item in the first iterable it performes another loop with the second one.

Comment: @pythonm: `(expr for i in iterable)` doesn't make a `tuple`.  That's a generator expression.  `tuple(expr for i in iterable)` would make a `tuple`.

Comment: Right, confused with the list [], dict {} and set {} comprehensions.

Comment: After reading pythonm comment and some tracing was able to understand what is happening. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `min` code is equivalent to using a [generator](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators) as follows:

```
def getPoints(point, numPoints):
  for i in range(numPoints - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, numPoints):
      yield (abs(point[i] - point[j]), (point[i], point[j]))

return min(getPoints(point, numPoints), key=itemgetter(0))
```

As @DSM noted, the first argument to `min` in your code is a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions).

Comment: Perfect. I did understand from the comments above, but seeing it this way was what I was looking for when I posed the question. Had not seen `yield` Thanks @jrennie.

Comment: @midniteOverflow FWIW, the StackOverflow convention is to "accept" and/or "upvote" if you think it was a good answer to your question.

Comment: apparently Vote Up requires 15 reputation